# Past Perfect: Although we had been good friends when we were young, I knew very little about him

Tags: grammar, tense, past-perfect

> Although we had been good friends when we were young, I knew very little about him.

Does the first sentence begin first before the second sentence in past or at the same time

Comment: There's only one sentence in your example.

Comment: Yes, that tense pushes actions further back. But all you need here is "Although we **were** good friends when we were young ..."

Comment: What @YosefBaskin said. The cited text is perfectly valid (it is Edgar Allen Poe, after all! :) but it's the *only* written instance of the sequence ["had been good friends when we were young"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22had+been+good+friends+when+we+were+young%22) in Google Books. As opposed to over a dozen *different* instances of ["were good friends when we were young"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22were+good+friends+when+we+were+young%22). But I always thought Poe was a bit long-winded anyway.

Comment: The cited text isn't precisely valid, though, because it doesn't mean what the author intends for it to mean, and it's useful to identify it as such because this is ELL. Language is useful inasmuch as it can be understood to mean what it is intended to mean, and the sentence, "We had been good friends when we were young," means that when we were young, we *had been* good friends. This puts the being of good friends in the past of the past--which is not the intention. Stick with "we were friends" to keep it in the timeframe of "when we were young".

Comment: @RMac - I don't agree. The sentence is part of a past-tense narrative, but in the first clause the narrator is looking back to an even earlier time, justifying the perfect tense.